# Include pdf at the end of a document

Tags: pdfpages

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
Some text.
\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.7]{myfirstfile.pdf}

more text
\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.7]{mysecondfile.pdf}
\chapter{chap2}
even more text

\end{document}
```

I would like that myfirstfile.pdf and mysecondfile.pdf would be printed at the end of the document, after chap1 and chap2. 
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\AtEndDocument` for that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\AtEndDocument{\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.7]{example-image-a}
\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.7]{example-image-b}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
Some text.


more text
\chapter{chap2}
even more text

\end{document}
```

As for your question in the comment: you can also do

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\AddGraphicsAtEnd}[2][pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.7]{%
\AtEndDocument{\includepdf[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
Some text.
\AddGraphicsAtEnd{example-image-a}


more text
\chapter{chap2}
even more text
\AddGraphicsAtEnd{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

i.e. just accumulate the stuff you want to put at the end.

Comment: Thanks! And is there anyway to renew includepdf command to do that by default? I mean, without actually writing \AtEndDocument everytime there is an includepdf command.

Comment: @AlejandroFernandez-Montes Sure. I added something along those lines to my answer.